# Office365 API returns 404 on GetCalendars on some accounts

Tags: calendar, office365, office365api

I'm using the Office365 as described in the [documenation website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Getcalendars) to get a user's calendars from Office365 account, but getting a 404 error instead:
`"GET /api/v1.0/Me/Calendars HTTP/1.1" 404`

The user has authorized access and I've managed to receive his personal details one request before.
 
The scopes I have authorized are `Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite UserProfile.Read`.
The access token response contains the endpoint URL and it's the one I'm using:
`'Calendar_api_endpoint': u'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0'`

**For most of the users, this operations works flawlessly. But for some it fails without any more information.**

In case an Office365 engineer sees this, here are the request IDs and time (UTC):
`2015-08-06 07:58:10.824550: Request id 2d3238e3-e3a6-436a-a2a6-5abb1f693e65 completed. Server id: 4c645b19-4a64-4203-8af5-7b4960f10593, Status: 404`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the cuff, you can see this error if the user's mailbox is not actually hosted in Office 365. For example, they may be in a hybrid scenario and their mailbox may be on an on-premise Exchange server. I'll ask our engineers to look at your request ID.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason, standing by for answers.

Comment: Another user received a **400** error for the same request. Here's the log for this one:
`2015-08-11 10:59:05.847610: Request id a80b74fa-22bd-45c1-8d83-eccbe8e833be completed. Server id: e39e2c44-cbfe-4ebd-9b5f-f746c6731048, Status: 400`

Comment: What Jason Johnston wrote was the scenario, confirmed with out users. No way to handle that, at least with those API. Maybe the new ones work differently for hybrids.